# How to query in mongoose for relational/nested schemas?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 Mongoose (5.9.25) schema models.
First, the GroupSchema model:

```
const GroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    admins: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    blocked: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    createdBy: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'user',
    },
    members: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    privacy: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['public', 'private', 'deleted'],
    },

})
```

Second, GroupPostSchema model:

```
const GroupPostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'user',
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    group: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'group',
    },
    image: {
        type: String
    }
})
```

I'm trying to query like this:

```
var search = {
    "group.privacy": "public"
}

GroupPostSchema.find(search).exec((err, data) => {
    // something
})
```

But its returning empty array []

I've read this answer:
[Mongoose query for nested schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63246081/mongoose-query-for-nested-schema)

But I want to keep `GroupPostSchema.group` as an Object not an Array.

How to do it the easiest way possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check without `exec` like this:

```js
const users = await User.find({'group.privacy': 'public'});
```

Comment: it shows error: "await is only valid in async function"

Comment: I actually have solved the problem using aggregator. Thanks btw